# Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

После приостановления моего сервера за неуплату(сервер был оплачен), после его запуска почему то апатч стал выдавать страницу по умолчанию Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page - что могло поменяться, проверил ХОСТЫ, настройки АПАТЧА - все  внорме. права на корневой каталог 775, в логах никаких записей нет - апатч до отключения нормально работал, и щас свободно перезагружается . Причем не загружается все ХОСТЫ

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте включены ли виртуалхосты:

```
sudo a2ensite example.org
```

Ну и не забудьте:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo a2ensite yapdomik.awolo.work.conf 
Site yapdomik.awolo.work already enabled

Comment: Вот не чего не помогает _ что бы я провалился сквозь пол )) - уже проверил всее )) Ну что могло поменяться

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться в саппорт, что они меняют, может дело не в ваших конфигах, или всё же в хостах если они скажут что ничего не меняли